# How to send ajax post array to mvc controller in vb.net

Tags: arrays, ajax, vb.net, post, controller

My javascript code;

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.Send', function () {
        var a = [];
        $(".k_sure").each(function () {
            var a_array= a.push($(this).val());
        });
        var b= [];
        $(".k_sure").each(function () {
            var b_array= a.push($(this).val());
        }); 
        var DataDiscount= { time: a_array, ind: b_array}; 
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/admin/pan/discount",
            data: DataDiscount,
            traditional: true,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (c) {  } 
            error: function () {   }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

My array;

DataDiscount:{time:["5","8","9"], ind:["%10","%15","%20"]}

my controller code;

```
Function discount(time As String, ind As String) As String 
        Dim x_add As New Discounts
        If x_add IsNot Nothing Then

            x_add.time = time 
            x_add.ind = ind
            db.Discounts.Add(x_add)
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return "Success"
        Else
            Return "Err"
        End If

        Return ""
    End Function
```

but only records the first data (5 and %10)
how to fix Controller code. My english is bad so sorry

Comment: you are passing arrays while your function is expecting strings?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your controller settings but you should send your data as a JSON object.

Try to JSON.stringify your data:

`var DataDiscount= JSON.stringify({ time: a_array, ind: b_array});`